# How many 6mm dowels to support a shelf of a given weight?

Tags: glue, mdf, dowel, weight-capacity

I’m building a bookshelf out of MDF (18mm thick) using 6mm dowels (Silverline brand like the dowelling jig).  Each shelf will be dowelled in place at the back and on both sides.

I’m concerned about whether the dowels will be strong enough for a heavily loaded shelf.

Is there a formula or rule of thumb that says how many 6mm dowels are required (or even what distance between dowels is required) to support a given shelf load (in kg) assuming the shelf is supported only by dowels on 3 sides?

I’m planning for the dowels to be glued.  Are there times when dowels are not enough and the shelf should also be glued, screwed or nailed in place?

Comment: There's no formula that I know of, and if there were it would need to be taken with a pinch of salt because dowel strength can vary *enormously* due to variation from piece to piece (see this [recent thread](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/9618) for a little on why). Additionally the length of the dowels and whether they go through the case or are in shallow holes are important factors, as is the quality of the MDF (it's not all equal, and the worst of it is pretty crumbly).

Comment: I think because of these many reasons, a lot of people switch to biscuits for MDF work like this.

Comment: One last pithy comment is that whenever I think about MDF work I always consider flat-pack furniture construction (the good and the bad) we've all seen too much of. How do Ikea, et al, engineer this sort of thing? What construction do they use for their items intended for more massive static forces? This will give you an idea of how they tune their construction for the material at hand and the loads involved.

Comment: @jdv *"I think because of these many reasons, a lot of people switch to biscuits for MDF work like this."* tee hee. I'm laughing because testing shows that dowel joinery is, and this is a surprise to most, actually hard to beat in terms of strength. I believe what happens when pros are weighing whether to go with a biscuit jointer or dowels that speed becomes the sole deciding factor in the majority of cases, despite the much higher initial spend and the higher ongoing costs with biscuits. Which is perfectly legit of course, clearly both are strong enough for most purposes, and time is money.

Comment: @Graphus yeah, the big win is speed for sure. Given that Ikea, et al, don't use biscuits, but opt for machines that can automate dowels and captured nuts it seems reasonable to assume both are acceptable -- if installed appropriately, which is what is asked here (and is actually hard to answer in a general manner, as you point out.)

Comment: Maybe provide a simple isometric drawing of the dimensions and fastening you are planning? It may help just look at your partially baked plans and leverage hive-mind eyeball engineering. As suggested, there's just no formula that can encapsulate all the variables of material and installation. My gut tells me that reasonable sized (and number of) dowels, properly glued-up, in reasonable quality MDF will handle pretty high static forces. Racking force is another question altogether, of course. Though, the failure mode for MDF is "sudden and complete", so YMMV.

Comment: Also, don't forget the internet; there are lots of published docs by magazine forums that discuss rules-of-thumb. "MSF dowels" got me lots of interesting hits.

Comment: Sterl, what this may boil down to is getting a gut read on what'll be strong enough for your application. And an obvious question needed for this that I forgot to ask earlier is, what's the max weight the shelves will be called upon to support? Readers may have a very different idea of "heavy loading" to what you have in mind. We also need to know what width and depth the shelves are.

Comment: IMO use short iron or steel rod lengths instead of wood dowels, for starters.

Comment: Metal would certainly be stronger.... but it's possibly overkill for a shelving unit where the shelf material itself may be likely to turn out to be the weak point ^_^ That aside, this doesn't Answer what was asked. It's fine to suggest alternatives, but it's considered good form to answer the Question as asked, then go on to give the alternate suggestion(s) if you have some and ideally with explanations for *why* they're better/more desirable, (e.g. stronger, less work, cheaper) or necessary (only safe to do it by a different method than asked).

Answer (score 1):

You can model each dowel and the shelf itself as beams. The dowels would be like a **uniformly distributed load cantilever**, while the shelf would be a **simply supported beam**. You can look up the material properties for your material type and input the parameters of your shelf in the calculators below.

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/timber-mechanical-properties-d_1789.html

Reasonable values would probably be yield strength of **50 MPa** and an elastic modulus of **10 GPa**.

Typically **deflection** or "sag" is the first area of concern for beams so I recommend solving for that first. I have attached a few calculators you can use for that.

https://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/cantilever-beams-d_1848.html

https://mechanicalc.com/calculators/beam-analysis/#divResults

You can also find the **maximum moment** and use the **flexure (bending) stress** equation in the link below to solve for stress and see if it is above the yield stress for your material type.
https://mechanicalc.com/reference/beam-analysis

Comment: This is great, but hard to apply here. The strength of the dowels is an unknown, and as mentioned in the first Comment above can vary *greatly* even for dowels of a known type (breaking strain in some could be as low as half that of the strongest).

Comment: Not to mention that those web refs will be moved or removed in an internet moment. To make this answer have a longer lifetime, maybe [edit] it and focus on the specific terms and notions that someone would use as jumping off points for study. That is, call out terms like "maximum moment" etc. and focus on those in your answer, with the links presented as short-lived examples.

Comment: @Graphus The link I provided has material properties for a wide variety of wood types. The actual strength doesn't need to be accurate, just double or triple the number of rods predicted to support the load. Breaking strain is a measure of displacement and isn't really relevant for this question. Stress is probably the word you are looking for.

Comment: @jdv Hopefully things are a little clearer now. The links are useful because you don't really need to understand the mechanics, you can just plug in values.

Comment: I will defer to your engineering knowledge 100%, but I know wood in a hands-on way backed up by published info that has looked at the material since the late 19th. c. The strength of the dowels **is** an unknown. If strength (however one needs to term it) can vary by a factor of 2 or more values given in some table are of limited practical use (esp. if not confirmed elsewhere). So say the solution on paper is to double or triple the number of dowels, that seems fine until you get to actually trying to do this, e.g. perfect alignment of 36 holes for one shelf! So *hard to apply here* is fair.

Comment: Heh, these comments remind me that one of the unofficial tenets of engineering with wood has often been "overbuild, overbuild, overbuild". Wood is tough stuff, and surprisingly strong in a variety of directions when compared with steel and concrete. But it is still a natural product that differs widely across applications -- hard to predict.